# Creating scroll gradient when div can be scrolled up or down?

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to create a scroll gradient at the bottom and top of my div so it is easier to see that the text is scrollable.

Right now you can see the gradient is at the top, but if I go to question_text:before and set bottom: 0; the gradient goes to the bottom of the screen instead of the bottom of the div.

The width also extends past the boundaries of the parent div (question).

What do I need to do to get an effect like this?

[Scroll gradient](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6IUa1.jpg)

https://codepen.io/SquanchyHappy/pen/mdmwRyy

The above link shows my full code, but the divs I'm trying to manipulate are below:

```
<div id="question" class="question resize">
    <div id="question_text" class="question-text">
        <span>Replace this with enough text to make scrollable.</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
.question {
    grid-rows: 1/2;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 3vh;
    padding-left: 0.5em;
    padding-right: 0.5em;
    padding-top: 0.5em;
    padding-bottom: 0.5em;
}

.question-text {
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    word-break: break-word;
    position: relative;
}

.question-text:before {
    content: "";
    width: 100%;
    height: 15%;
    position: fixed;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%);
}
```